# How can I fix a BTRFS "parent transid verify failed" error?

Tags: apt, kernel, dpkg, btrfs

I'm new to Ubuntu and I think something went wrong while performing apt upgrades. The unattended upgrades fail due to this error message:

```
dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten des Paketes linux-headers
      /usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-112/drivers/thermal/ti-soc-thermal/Makefile.dpkg-tmp
      kann nicht  auf sichere Weise entfernt werden: Input/output error
```

As I wanted to remove this file manually, I followed the path to `/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-112/drivers`. Unfortunately I'm not able to open the thermal directory due to this error message while trying to open it.

[image: btrfs error while trying to open thermal directory]

```
[ 2993.676128] BTRFS error (device dm-0): parent transid verify failed on 220839936 wanted 376721 found 373009
[ 2993.676740] BTRFS error (device dm-0): parent transid verify failed on 220839936 wanted 376721 found 373009
[ 2993.677401] BTRFS error (device dm-0): parent transid verify failed on 220839936 wanted 376721 found 373009
[ 2993.678033] BTRFS error (device dm-0): parent transid verify failed on 220839936 wanted 376721 found 373009
[ 2993.678810] BTRFS error (device dm-0): parent transid verify failed on 220839936 wanted 376721 found 373009
[ 2993.679552] BTRFS error (device dm-0): parent transid verify failed on 220839936 wanted 376721 found 373009 
-bash: cd: thermal: Input/output error
```

I'm not unable to install updates at all, but this one fails every day. Is there any possibility to fix this error?

Comment: Does the error still occur after a `btrfs scrub`?